# Common way to get BIOS information via C

Tags: c, bios

After reading some stuff it seems I can map the SMBIOS memory and parse it.
I have no idea on how to go about this.
I can't use any managed code as I would like this to be compilable under any OS.

Does anyone have any code examples how to go about this?

Comment: What BIOS information do you need?  If you're using Windows, there might be WMI interfaces that expose certains aspects of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On most systems, it is not mapped into user-mode accessible memory, so you need to call some system API.

On Windows, you can call [GetSystemFirmwareTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724379(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For Linux I guess you should have a look at the **dmidecode** [source](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/) (GPL) for concrete code...

Using and parsing dmidecode output may be all you need...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a reusable class to read all the SMBIOS stuff.

It is very clean code with a proper error handling and easy to extend. 
You can derive a class from this class that uses the parsed data to display it or do whatever you want with it.

You find also a link to the actual SMBios documentation in the code's comments.

You can download it from my homepage: 
ftp://ftp.netcult.ch/mirror/elmue/SMBiosClass.zip

Elmue

Answer (score 0):

if you can run DOS programs (e.g. 32-bit Windows) it is mapped to f000:f000
Otherwise, you would need to figure out a way to map it yourself or find an API to help you (as suggested in previous posts).